# Sonar - "make it so!"

Tags: sonarqube

Can Sonar be configured with a "make it so!" capability?

Many of its suggestions could then be effected by just clicking a button in the UI, instead of having to use my IDE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a feature request in an open-source software.

Answer (score 2):

No. You'll have to modify the code manually.